# calculate the number of sprinklers I can have in a ceiling and where each sprinkler would connect with the water pipes

Tags: c#, algorithm, pseudocode

So basically programmatically, given 4 3D coordinates for the ceiling of a room as well as 3 pairs of 3D coordinates for the water pipes above the ceiling I am to calculate how many sprinklers I can have in the ceiling if each sprinkler has to be 2500mm from the walls and apart from each other.

I could write out the program but the problem is I don't know how this is calculated.

The problem:

> calculate the number of sprinklers, their positions on the room’s ceiling and connect each sprinkler to the nearest water pipe.
>
> The room has a rectangular shape. Ceiling coordinates (x, y, z) are:

```
(97500.00, 34000.00, 2500.00)
(85647.67, 43193.61, 2500.00)
(91776.75, 51095.16, 2500.00)
(103629.07, 41901.55, 2500.00)
```

> Three water pipes are available:

```
(98242.11, 36588.29, 3000.00) to (87970.10, 44556.09, 3500.00)
(99774.38, 38563.68, 3500.00) to (89502.37, 46531.47, 3000.00)
(101306.65, 40539.07, 3000.00) to (91034.63, 48506.86, 3000.00)
```

> Sprinklers are to be placed on the ceiling 2500mm away from the walls and from each other.
> Please, calculate the number of sprinklers that can be fitted into this room, then calculate
> coordinates (x, y, z) of each sprinkler.
> For each sprinkler calculate coordinates (x, y, z) of the connection point to the nearest water pipe.

Now I understand that the distance formula between two 3d points is `d = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2)`.

But I'm not sure how to calculate the number of sprinklers using this. or how to calculate their points of intersection on the water pipes. if i could calculate their points of intersection on each pipe and the distance from that point to each sprinkler, then the nearest pipe would be obvious and that would be the pipe the sprinkler connects to.

I have to write this using c# and the dotnet framework. But would I be able to please get some assistance putting this into the form of pseudocode and understanding how to approach, tackle and calculate this problem? I'm not good at the maths side of this but hopefully once understanding how it is solved, I can then possibly put this into a c# function.

Answer (score 0):

This question is so elaborated that, even in pseudocode, it's a big deal.
You might start with a re-calibration of your rectangle (indeed, the four coordinates you provide form a rectangle indeed): you shift your entire rectangle so that one point equals (0,0). The you rotate your rectangle in order for your rectangle to have following coordinates:

```
(0,0)
(Xmax, 0)
(0, Ymax)
(Xmax, Ymax)
```

Once you have this, you can start looking for your algorithm for filling the ceiling with sprinklers. First you can base yourself on this "algorithm":

- Fill your rectangle with squares where the length of the line equals two times the given radius.

Once you have this, you can upgrade to the following "algorithm":

- Fill your rectangle with circles with the given radius.

Revert everything to the original coordinates (rotating back and shifting back).

Once you have this, you might start calculating the distances to the pipes, using basic "distance-between-point-and-line" formula.

Comment: this is a nice suggestion but a few questions about this:
- i could calculate the lengths of the rectangle from point to point. this proves to be something like 15000 x 10000 x 2500.. I could translate the points to something like (0, 0), (15, 0), (0, 10), (15, 10)... but then how would I translate that back when I am to calculate the points of all the sprinklers?
- there is no radius just distance apart
- I am not sure how to calculate the number of sprinklers
- given only the two ends of the water pipes how would we get point of intersection to calculate distance?

Comment: would you know of any similar problems with example solutions?

Comment: This is the core of my solution: you create a bunch of figures (first try with squares, then with circles), where the radius is half of the distance, and you fill your rectangle with those figures in an optimal way (there might be an infinite number of solutions).

Comment: About the translation, sorry for that (I'm a native Dutch speaking): I meant a "*shift*": you can first shift your rectangle until one point reaches (0,0) and then rotate for the sides of your rectangle to fall on X and Y axis. Afterwards you can just rotate and shift back. (In Dutch, "shift" is "translatie", hence my mistake)

Comment: that makes sense visually. however is there a mathematical way to do this (the shifting for every point to calculate what it would be on the axis, and then how to shift / rotate back)?

Comment: wait by shift - you mean translate, right? so translate one point to the origin and then do the rotation so that the rectangle sits on the x axis... yes that makes perfect sense.
Then it would be easier to iterate through and determine coordinates.
Then for each of those coordinates perform the reverse operation (-rotate, -translate).

How can I learn how to do these operations with matrices and 3d space? i also might need to relearn matrix operations...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the ceiling can be tiled with 4x6 squares of side 2500 mm. That tells you the number of sprinklers.

You can find their positions by computing vectors of length 2500 mm, parallel to the sides (first compute unit vectors). It is not too difficult to obtain then coordinates using a matrix arrangement.

Next, you compute the distance of every sprinkler to the three pipes and keep the shortest. (CAUTION: distance to the line segments, not to the lines of support.)

Comment: sorry to trouble you.... i can understand better now what you mean by fill it up with squares (how did you get 4 x 6?). the sprinkler being in the bottom right of each square (where the lines intersect). Are there some resources I can look at in order to understand how I can compute the parallel vectors or how the matrix arrangement works? I haven't done that kind of math in many years.

I assume once I have each (x,y,z) coordinates of each sprinkler there is a formula that calculates the distance from each of those points to each of those 3 lines (the waterpipes)?

Comment: @royt85: draw it on paper, you will better understand (the z values do not matter).

Comment: drawing it on paper i see that it is a rotated rectangle which is not sitting parallel to the x or y axis. i just have to figure out how to calculate the other three points were i to move one corner to (0,0). Also how would I perform the reverse operation once I have calculated all the points while we are sitting parallel to the axis, to convert back to the original points?

Comment: @royt85: You can find their positions by computing vectors of length 2500 mm, parallel to the sides (first compute unit vectors).

Comment: i have no idea how to do that. what can i study to better understand what you are talking about?

Comment: @royt85: this is basic vector algebra. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Basic_properties

Comment: if it's basic, how would you work out the solution? for completion sake?